# Can’t find the grammar error in the the sentence

Tags: grammar

I recently came across a sentence which was grammatically wrong, but I couldn’t understand why. I’ll appreciate if you could help. 
The sentence reads,  “I find Chinese English quiet funny, because they don’t use proper English grammar”

Comment: I suspect that "quiet" should be "quite" and it's missing a full stop at the end.

Comment: What makes you think it could be "grammatically wrong?" What part of it is troubling you?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to be noted in the above mentioned sentence:

1. The word 'quite' must be used insted of 'quiet'.

> ```
> Quite means to a certain or fairly significant extent or degree; fairly.
>
> Quiet means making little or no noise.
> ```

2. There's no need of using a comma before 'because' as it's preceding a dependent clause. For more information [see this link](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-because/) in regard to comma usage before the word 'because'. But using comma doesn't make the sentence grammatically incorrect, it's just unnecessary.

Therefore, we conclude that the more grammatically well structures sentence is:

> I find Chinese English **quite** funny **because** they don’t use
>   proper English grammar. [Correct]

Comment: That comma use is not an error by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong pronoun.  "They" is not the correct antecedent for "Chinese English".

“I find Chinese English [quite] funny, because *it* doesn’t use proper English grammar.”

According to Fowler's the comma may be used, depending on context.  That said, a good maxim is *the fewer commas the better*.

Comment: I agree with this answer and wonder what the score of -1 represents about it. The sudden "they" is not a grammatical error, exactly, but the lack of any plural noun to which "they" might be related seems to be the problem here.

Comment: It's a grammatical error because "Chinese English" is singular, but "they" is plural–pronoun-antecedent disagreement. I think "they" contemplates Chinese people, but they're not in the sentence, just then singular "Chinese English".  The -1 may be over the comma, which is a pedant's being silly.  Use it or not, no biggie.

Comment: Well I see that way of looking at it. But I would assume that the context was something like this. "Many Chinese people study English in school. They believe it will help them in the global economy. But they don't speak it at home. I find Chinese English quite funny, because they don’t use proper English grammar.” In other words, the author conceived of the words "Chinese grammar" as equal to "the grammar of Chinese people." If I'm right about that, then in context it would be clear that "they" refers not to grammar, but to Chinese people. Still, it's a distracting jump.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but interpreting "Chinese English" as "people (plural) of Chinese descent who are now considered British citizens who live in England" or similar sidesteps the issue with the pronoun. Alternatively, 'singular they' also sidesteps the problem neatly, as does metonymy.